# Switch from Android to window

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot

I have a dual booted Android-Windows 10 tablet.

Recently to get some space on Windows I deleted the Android files through Windows mode. After sometime I have switched to Android just to see what happen. Now it is in bootloop.

All I want is to switch to Windows mode back. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. In order for anyone to help with a problem like this, you need to include the model and manufacturer of your device. Also, please include any information about troubleshooting that you have done yourself.

Comment: When it loops, does Windows appear at all, or does it just make it to BIOS?

Comment: Its a laptop from datamini TWG10. Its show the company name and than blank and than again company and this keep on repeating. Sometime it's also show Android boot error. I can go to bootloader using volume up bottom but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: possible help https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software-hacking/fetching-twg10-factory-imgs-t3703214

Comment: Do you have access to a laptop or other device like a PC which can help you fix this device ? Have you heard of Windows Phone Internals, maybe this can help? https://www.wpinternals.net/index.php/downloads

Comment: Yah I have a pc installed with windows 7. u/vssher I think you have misunderstood what I want to say. I have a tablet with Android and windows 10 dual booted . It is not a windows phone.